# PyCharm hide files by pattern

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm project view, how can I hide files by pattern? E.g. hide `*.sqlite` or all hidden (`.*`) files?

I've looked at many settings and tried searching, but no luck.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types --> Ignore files and folders`

This will **permanently** hide all of such files. Since this is an IDE-wide setting, it will affect ALL projects and such files will be **excluded** from the project.

---

**Alternatively** -- use `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes` and define custom scope with desired files only (or exclude all unwanted). This is per-project setting and you can define as many scopes as you want.

Once done -- you can switch to that scope in Project View panel (choose desired scope instead of default "Project").

Answer (score 18):

1. Go to the settings in pycharm

   [image]
2. In 'Appearance & Behaviour' select scopes:
   [image]
3. Add a scope:
   [image]
4. Name that scope:
   [image]
5. Now you can enter either a pattern or select folder to include or exclude:
   [image]
6. Now switch to the which was just defined:

   [image]

In 'Exclude_cached_scrapy_files' you will not see the excluded files. A scope can be a specific files or folders or files and folders following a patterns.