How to hide the __init__.py in every directory
I have a repo filled with lots of nested directories; in almost everyone, I  have a __init__.py file. The problem is it makes it harder to visually search directories for the files, and it was noticeable when the directory only contained 1 Python code file alongside __init__.py
So my question is:

Is there any way to hide the file in IDE (PyCharm in my case) to not show this file without affecting the functionality?

I have tried to exclude it from PyCharm from General > File Types but that breaks the code because it is not simply hiding the files from the codebase.
for reference:
I am new to the project and not so experienced, so hiding the init files will help me to focus only on the code files and folder construction design, and learn about the code that I'm going to deal with, for now.

For most of us, it is important to see them. We may use just directory with one init.py (and no other files), so it depends much on how you are organizing your code. Maybe too many files in one directory?

But what is you problem about harder to search directories? Maybe you should uses other search tools (I search for file name, identifiers, etc., seldom I explicit navigate to files)

I am new to the project and not so experienced, so hiding the init files will help me to focus only on the code files, for example.I can't understand why so much negativity and hate here?))) if this does hurt your feelings I can remove it from here guys, I needed help, not an opinion, just simple help))

@GiacomoCatenazzi this is not about search tools, it was a visual Inspection of the repo to get some understanding about what is where, firstly I need to know about the file names to be able to use search tools to find them. This is just my preference and even though I think you have a valid point that it cannot hurt any search engine to search for the file, but for me, I need to see the code files without init. It's like if I ask - how to make terminal prompts colorful,

For me init (which it is also the first file) describe the directory. so module/__init__.py is about module.. OTOH you come from Java, you may get more used to files and meaning. Just with Python (and other language) you will forgot them (for sure not as first class citizen). I think it is a reason it is not filtered out (and it may contain useful code) -- something biologist call use it or lose it. By not being important, we tend not to thing much about files

That's a good point, I agree with that. As I have mentioned earlier, it is just a preference for now to ease my life)) I don't have anything against that file, but when you open 5 nested directories to find 1 particular file to understand how the folder construction was designed in the company, the init files are annoying, especially when you can simply look at the directory tree and by the dot on the folder icon you can understand does it contain init or it's a simple folder, so at the same time, you have an understanding about the repo and you can look after more important files in my case.

@Luuk as you maybe missed this part I will cite again:

I have tried to exclude it from PyCharm from General > File Types but that breaks the code because it is not simply hiding the files from the codebase.


"Alternatively -- use Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes and define custom scope with desired files only (or exclude all unwanted). This is per-project setting and you can define as many scopes as you want." (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23539618/724039)

@Luuk indeed, it is the same question, sorry for bothering you, and thank you for mentioning it, I have already marked it as duplicated. Thank you for your contribution

In JetBrains IDE there is feature called scope. Just go to your project bar, and press three dots:

After that press Edit Scopes, you will see this window

In this window press + key, choose any type (local for example), enter name of your scope (for me it's test) and in field patter type this !file:*__init__.py. Press Apply and then OK

After that in your Project bar you can click on Project and instead of Project choose your scope. That's it


